# Using if(char == '\n') to reset variables C++

Tags: c++, function, variables, newline

I've set this up so the code will read from the file and reset a variable (count) to 0 when the program reads in a new line or line break via the if(ch == '\n') statement.  However it doesn't see this no matter where I put it.

So My question is:

What is the proper way to reset a variable when a program reads in a new line?

(Just for reference the data file I'm working with is very simple, it looks like this:

TIGER

DOG

RACCOON

ZEBRA

AARDVARK

HIPPOPOTAMUS

CAT

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

void rectangle(char ch, int alphacount,int count)
{
for ( int height = 0; height < count; ++height )
{
  for ( int width = 0; width < alphacount; ++width )
  {
     fout << ch;
     cout << ch;
  }
  fout << endl;
  cout << endl;
 }
}

int main(void)
{
fin.open("animals.dat");
fout.open("out.dat");
int count=0, alphacount=0;
char ch, x='A';
while(!fin.eof())
{
int alphacount = 0;
count++;
char ch;
fin.get(ch);
if ( isalpha(ch) )
{
  if ( ch > 'Z' )
  {
     // It's a lower case letter.
     alphacount = ch - 'a' + 1;
  }
  else
  {
     // It's an upper case letter.
     alphacount = ch - 'A' + 1;
  }
if(ch == '\n')
  {
    cout << endl;
    fout << endl;
    count = 0;
}

  rectangle(ch, alphacount, count);


 }


}

}
```

*EDIT:*

Started using `fin.get(ch)` instead of `fin >> ch;`

But no dice, it's still not picking up the line break if statement.

Comment: `fin >> ch` will not get whitespace or newlines.

Comment: You may want to look into [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) as well.

Comment: I'm a beginning programmer. If fin >> ch won't work for this, could you give me an example of how to use getline (or anything else) for this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
fin.get(ch);
```

in place of the `fin >> ch;` line.  For additional details, check out: [std::basic_istream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).  To be absolutely sure the `ch` variable has new content, use the `fail()` method before any processing (e.g. reference: [std::basic_ios::fail](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail)).  An example:

```
if ( isalpha(ch) && !fin.fail())
{
.
.
.
```

The basic fstream reference is here: [std::basic_fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Comment: When I change `fin >> ch` to `fin.get(ch)` it says I'm using an uninitialized variable 'ch'.

Comment: @Skathix This is a true statement.  The `ch` variable can always be set to something meaningful when it is declared.  Then the logic reacts accordingly in case the `get` fails.

Comment: That one was my fault I was double initializing the variable and calling it in the `fin.get(ch)` statement as well. But dammit all if it's not picking up that line

Comment: I changed the `fin >> ch;` to `fin.get(ch);`.

The `isalpha(ch)` part was also messing me up, so I wrote in 

`if(!fin.fail()){
.
.
.
`
The two of these combined ended up giving me exactly the result I needed, thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: @Skathix You are welcome.  Be sure to use the links to the different areas of the `fstream` references.  I am confident they will continue to help.